# Why is there no salt bridge for hydrogen–silver bromide cell?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, electrochemistry

What is the reason there is no salt bridge for this cell?

$$\ce{Pt(s) | H2(g) | HBr(aq) | AgBr(s) | Ag(s)}$$

Answer (score 2):

The function of a salt bridge or a diaphragm is to avoid mixing of 2 different electrolytes or electrolysis products from the respective half-cells, while allowing ion electro-migration between them.

This cell does not need a salt bridge as it uses the only electrolyte $\ce{HBr(aq)}$ and the is no need to separate the $\mathrm{AgBr}$ electrode from gaseous hydrogen.